# Delete user from MySQL table if no other users exist with similar traits

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table called tbl_test in a MySQL database :

```
+------+------------+------------+
| name | fav_color  | dob        |
+======+============+============+
| jane | blue       | 1996-07-07 |
+------+------------+------------+
| jane | pink       | 1996-07-07 |
+------+------------+------------+
| jane | pink       | 2016-07-07 |
+------+------------+------------+
| joe  | pink       | 2001-07-07 |
+------+------------+------------+
| john | red        | 1997-07-07 |
+------+------------+------------+
```

In English, here's what I want to accomplish:

delete all users with dob < 2001-01-01 but keep a user if there exists another user with the same name AND fav_color whose dob >= 2001-01-01.

So in this example, the jane whose favorite color is blue and john would be deleted.

So far, I've tried:

```
DELETE FROM tbl_test
WHERE dob < '2000-01-01' AND name, fav_color NOT IN
(SELECT T.name, T.fav_color FROM
(SELECT name, fav_color FROM tbl_test WHERE dob >= '2000-01-01') T);
```

But MySQL throws a syntax error when I enter this command. Any tips for how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL doesn't let you refer to the table being deleted in the rest of the statement.  So:

```
DELETE t
    FROM tbl_test t LEFT JOIN
         (SELECT t2.name, t2.fav_color
          FROM tbl_test t2
          WHERE dob >= '2000-01-01'
         ) tt
         ON t.name = tt.name AND t.fav_color = tt.fav_color
    WHERE t.dob < '2000-01-01' AND tt.name IS NULL;
```

Your method is very reasonable.  And, you do have some other syntax errors (such as the first argument to `NOT IN` should have parentheses).  Even if you fix those, though, you'll have a problem with the query.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is exactly what you want, but your use of `IN` is not correct. I think you want to use `EXIST` (or in this case `NOT EXIST`)

```
DELETE FROM tbl_test
WHERE dob < '2000-01-01' 
AND NOT EXIST(
    SELECT null FROM tbl_test as tt
    WHERE tt.name = tbl_test.name
        AND tt.fav_color = tbl_test.fav_color
        AND dob >= '2000-01-01'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without subqueries by using an *exclusion join*.

Try to join a user "t1" to another user "t2" with the criteria you describe. If none is found, the OUTER JOIN will make all columns NULL for t2. Where this happens, delete t1.

```
DELETE t1
FROM tbl_test AS t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_test AS t2
  ON t1.name = t2.name AND t1.fav_color = t2.fav_color AND t2.dob >= '2000-01-01'
WHERE t1.dob < '2000-01-01'
  AND t2.name IS NULL;
```